# I can't fire event when clicking on tab page in MS Access 2007

Tags: ms-access

I have a click_event handler on a Tab page but when I click on it, nothing occurs and with debug I can see it is never triggered.

Is this a bug ?

Comment: Aside from the fact that the click event of a tab page is probably one of the least useful places you could put your code, try copying your code to the clipboard, then going through the property sheet to re-assign the code to the event. The connections between the events and the code assigned to them sometimes get lost and you have to recreate them. But you should also consider whether you ought to be using the tab control's OnChange event instead.

Comment: I can't see no OnChange event only click event.

Comment: Probably because there isn't one for pages, only for the tab contol itself.

Answer (score 1):

When code starts misbehaving, it is often worth trying decompile.

http://www.granite.ab.ca/access/decompile.htm